# Django client login redirect loop

Tags: python, django, redirect

New to django and attempting to solve current problems with company web portal. When logging into the site with a staff account the login works fine, but using a client account returns the ERR::TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

```
def user_login(request):
# Like before, obtain the context for the user's request.
context = RequestContext(request)
form = AuthenticationForm()
# If the request is a HTTP POST, try to pull out the relevant information.
if request.method == 'POST':
    # Gather the username and password provided by the user.
    # This information is obtained from the login form.
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']

    # Use Django's machinery to attempt to see if the username/password
    # combination is valid - a User object is returned if it is.
    try:
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    except LockedOut:
        messages.error(request, 'You have been locked out because of too many login attempts. Please try again in 10 minutes.')

    # If we have a User object, the details are correct.
    # If None (Python's way of representing the absence of a value), no user
    # with matching credentials was found.
    else:
        if user:
            # Is the account active? It could have been disabled.
            if user.is_active:
                # If the account is valid and active, we can log the user in.
                # We'll send the user back to the homepage.
                login(request, user)
                if request.user.is_client:
                    messages.error(request, 'Something is not working correctly.')
                elif request.user.is_staff:
                    return redirect('home')

            else:
                # An inactive account was used - no logging in!
                messages.error(request, 'Your account is disabled.')

        else:
            messages.error(request, 'The credentials you entered are invalid.')
# Bad login details were provided. So we can't log the user in.
# The request is not a HTTP POST, so display the login form.
# This scenario would most likely be a HTTP GET.
# No context variables to pass to the template system, hence the
# blank dictionary object...
#return render_to_response('administrative/login.html', {'form': form}, context)
return redirect('administrative/login.html')
```

When this code is run using a staff account the `redirect('home')` works fine, but the client accounts wont even run the error message, they just immediately redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're redirecting to a page that also redirects, most likely because there user isn't logged in.

Comment: but if the user is a client then there is no redirection happening, or am i missing something?